# {"error":"unsupported_grant_type"} while get token from my rest api on flutter

Tags: javascript, rest, http, dart, flutter

Here is my main.dart:

Future getData() async {

```
 Map<String, String> connection = {

    "grant_type": "string",
    "branchcode": "string",
    "password": "string",
    "username": "string",
    "dbname": "string",
    "dbuser": "string",
    "dbpassword": "string",
    "dbtype": "string"

  };


  Uri apiUrl = Uri.http("192.168.1.23:7070", "/api/v2/token",connection);
  HttpClientRequest request = await new HttpClient().getUrl(apiUrl);
  HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
  Stream resStream = response.transform(utf8.decoder);

  await for(var apiKey in resStream){
    print(apiKey);
  }
}
```

I have rest api my own ip address. When ı was tried to connect this Map<> string to api it will return a {"error":"unsupported_grant_type"} error.
How can ı fix this problem ?

Comment: try with this https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http

Comment: It looks like you are actually sending the word `string` ?